# User defined value in a comparison operation

Tags: pandas

I have data in two formats, df1 and df2. df1 is a list containing dataframes and df2 is a dataframe. I want to compare a value (cut_off) to a specific column of the two dataframes (score). I want to replace the value by a user defined value. How can can I do it?

```
cut_off = [1,2,3,4]
df_elements = [df1.sample(n=12) for i in range(100)] #randomly selecting 12 rows from a big set

for co in cut_off:
    print ("set1 : " + str((df_elements[1]['score'] > co).sum())) 
    print("set2 : " + str((df2['score'] > co).sum()))
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you write an example of data and desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with:

```
df['specific_column'] = df['specific_column'].replace(['123', '12'], '5')
```

`['123', '12']` are the values you want to replace `'5'` is value which will replace it.